# TestFlight: Missing Session and Crash counts

Tags: session, crash, testflight, xcode10

Has anyone encountered missing session and crash counts in TestFlight? Wondering if the latest Xcode 10.0 update changed a plist setting or ?

Comment: I've submitted an Apple dev support ticket. All the counts are missing, not just for a particular subset of users.